# Java Vectors : Implementing Pop function using Vectors

Tags: java, vector

What is difference between `a.remove(a.size()-1)` and `a.remove(a.indexOf(a.lastElement()))` of Vectors Class in Java? Do they remove the same element?

`a.remove(a.indexOf(a.lastElement()))` gave me wrong output whereas `a.remove(a.size()-1)` is giving correct output.

Note: `a` is a Java Vector declared as

```
Vector<Integer> a = new Vector<Integer>();
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. If you get "wrong" output, why dont you show us some example data? (where the quick answer might be: you have duplicates in the vector, so that LAST element shows up in OTHER places, too. So `indexOf()` will return the FIRST occurrence  , not necessarily the last one.

Comment: And note the javadoc of that class: As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to implement the List interface, making it a member of the Java Collections Framework. Unlike the new collection implementations, Vector is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector.

Comment: Or, if you want to create a stack or queue, use `ArrayDeque`.

Answer (score 0):

`a.remove(a.indexOf(a.lastElement()))` is a very roundabout way of achieving roughly the same thing.

It gets the lasts element in the vector, tries to find the index of any element that is `equal` to it and then removes that element.

That is only **roughly** the same as `a.remove(a.size()-1)`, because if the vector contains a second object that is `equal` to the last one (i.e. `last.equals(otherElement)` returns `true`), then that item will be removed instead.

`a.remove(a.size()-1)` is definitely the more correct (and faster) way to remove the last element.